# How to fix a faulty old LCD that flickers?

Tags: lcd

User `dmcdivitt`'s helpful comments under this original at [Lifehacks SE](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/5592/1869) inspired this post. I indeed am awaiting his/her unification of his comments to answer this question her, for the benefit of others.

> [image]

Probably due to old age, the screen of my old Sony SDM M51 monitor flickers. The Sony representative advised that inside the lower left side (hereinafter abbreviated as LS) of the monitor (as depicted in red above), parts nearing the front of the screen have loosened from parts at the back. So  the only solution is to clench, grip, or squeeze the front and back of the red area (eg by hand), which has eliminated the flickers for the past years. Alas, the detachment worsened a few days ago, to the extent that my hands hurt and the LS now needs continual compression and grasp to stop flickering.

So what can I use to resolve this problem? I tried a large binder clip which only works when my hand clings to the clip; as soon as I stop holding onto the clip, it flings itself off because the LS is too thick.

Footnote: Please advise on other words to describe this problem (I struggle to find the perfect diction). [Here is a sample Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sony%20sdm%20m51&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=jknrVJqmOY6wyATShYDoAQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1536&bih=744#imgdii=_&imgrc=AfDlkr0XEoVK8M%253A%3BIQbuHrwk8CCCHM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fpc.watch.impress.co.jp%252Fdocs%252Farticle%252F20000803%252Fsony.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fpc.watch.impress.co.jp%252Fdocs%252Farticle%252F20000803%252Fsony.htm%3B640%3B483)%20effected%20[the%20original%20image](http://pc.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/article/20000803/sony.jpg) for what I believe the problem is.

Comment: Buy a small wood clamp at a hardware store. :)

Comment: @Xavierjazz Thank you. Please feel free to post this at Lifehacks!

Comment: @Xavierjazz Sorry, I'm unsure of your meaning? I had intended to ask you if you could do so?

Comment: If you are technically proficient, you may be able able to repair the monitor yourself, but it will take major disassembly, might not be successful, and you would risk damaging it worse.  Given the relative low cost of a new monitor, it typically isn't cost effective to have a shop repair it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was at lifehacks.se.

Why not take the monitor apart and see what needs to be pressed together? A little inspection would help. That way you know exactly what you're dealing with. Maybe a shim can be put inside allowing the body or case to hold it in place.

First unplug. LCD monitors do not have residual voltage risk like monitors with tubes. Pay attention so you can put everything back! Look for screws and take them out. Remove all screws found before trying to separate. Even if all screws are out there may be plastic catches still holding it together. When you take it apart, components will be secured by other screws inside. Do not stretch any wires. Find the spot where disfunctionality exists and see what to do. When putting back together, make sure wires are not trapped or squeezed by the case or shell.